# Inversion in the sentence: "More substantially dealt with is a suggestion [...]"

Tags: grammar, inversion

In *The Independent* I [found](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/media/tv-radio/ukraine-crisis-could-russia-today-turn-you-into-a-putin-propagandist-9174759.html) this sentence:

> **More substantially dealt with is a suggestion, repeated over the phone by an Estonian minister to EU foreign affairs chief Cathy
>   Ashton, that the snipers who killed so many protesters in Kiev were
>   cynical opposition plants.**

I would like to know whether the inversion is used at the beginning of the sentence.  I was taught that inversion is possible when using e.g. hardly, never, little, seldom.

Comment: It's a nice and well constructed sentence. My guess is that the inversion was written to place **suggestion** and **that the snipers....** part close to each other, because **suggestion** = **that the snipers ...**

Comment: I expect the previous sentence to talk about how some other point was glossed over and the writer wanted to contrast the substance here with the lack of it on that previous point.  To do that, the "*dealing with*" was brought forward to prominence in this sentence.

Comment: This article helps and lists some adverbs susceptible to this inversion: http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/inversion.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was taught that inversion is possible when using e.g. hardly, never, little, seldom.

That is true. Those words are all adverbs that trigger subject–auxiliary inversion, producing a sentence with the structure "{adverb} {auxiliary verb} {subject} {rest of predicate}".

But the example in your question is quite different. "More substantially dealt with" is effectively an *adjective*: it's the complement of *is*. So the structure of your example sentence is "{subject complement} {form of *be*} {subject}".

Although it's not obvious from your example, this is not ordinary subject–auxiliary inversion, in that it's not restricted to just an auxiliary verb. For example, consider this sentence:

> Even more pervasive **have been** complaints about guards running wild. [[link](http://online.wsj.com/articles/SB116173782126202804)]

Had this been subject–auxiliary inversion, the word *been* would have come *after* the subject.

Rather, this is a special pattern where the subject and the subject complement have completely switched places; instead of the usual "{subject} {form of *be*} {subject complement}", we have "{subject complement} {form of *be*} {subject}".

The decision to use this pattern is made for stylistic reasons rather than syntactic ones, so it's hard to give cut-and-dried rules; but in your example, I think the writer selected it for two reasons:

1. The subject complement — "More substantially dealt with" — makes it clear how the sentence relates to the previous topic. It allows a new topic to be introduced without seeming abrupt. (In writing education, this is often called a "transition".)
2. The subject — "a suggestion, repeated over the phone by an Estonian minister to EU foreign affairs chief Cathy Ashton, that the snipers who killed so many protesters in Kiev were cynical opposition plants" — is very long. There is a general tendency in English for long or "heavy" phrases to be pushed toward the end of a sentence.

Comment: Surely the example sentence is of the form (ignoring the better positioning of the **adverb** 'better' immediately after the auxiliary): [This suggestion] [was dealt with] [better] where 'deal with' is a transitive MWV. 'Better' is an adjunct. There is no subject complement. _They handled it well_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It sounds like you want to treat "was dealt with" as an indivisible syntactic unit, as its Latin counterpart would be? But I think the OP's sentence is, in itself, proof that we can't always treat it that way. "N is dealt with ADV" *means* the same thing as "[unspecified party] deals with N ADV", but its *syntax* is different. The participial complement "dealt with" can precede the copula "is", can govern its own modifiers, etc.

Comment: "N is dealt with sensitively" compares with "N is handled sensitively". Admittedly, 'N has been handled." isn't available. // "More substantially dealt with is a suggestion ..." is comparable to "More swiflly handled was the suggestion ..." with a fronted adverbial.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I agree that your example of "More swiftly handled was the suggestion [...]" is structurally the same as the OP's example; but I think you are misanalyzing both. In your example, "more swiftly" modifies "handled", and the complement "more swiftly handled" and subject "the suggestion [...]" have switched places from the more-common structure "the suggestion [...] was more swiftly handled". Neither example has a fronted adverbial.

Comment: It's merely a style-driven inversion of 'The suggestion ... was handled more swiftly'. NP + Vpass +Advbl

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think you're mistaken -- as the OP's example demonstrates, "Vpass" isn't a real constituent in English -- but do feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: [The authors] [deal with / treat / discuss] [suggestion B] [[more] thoroughly]. // [Suggestion B] [is] [dealt with] [in greater detail]. 'In greater detail' or 'thoroughly / more thoroughly' or 'more substantially' are adverbials of degree. Fronting any that can be doesn't change that.